# Calculations on heat transfers

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

An unclothed person whose body has a surface area of 1.4m^2 with emissivity of 0.85 has a skin temperature of 37 °C standing in a 20 °C room. How much heat does the person lose per minute?

Comment: This sounds like homework. What did you try to solve the problem?

Comment: googling this question yield at least couple of sources with explicit answer

Comment: Hi Kylie and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Try using Stephan-Boltzmann law to answer this question, here's a link that might help you:
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/stefan.html